# for xml root('someStr'),type) ''sub-element issue"

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'm building this xml element using the code below

```
,( select 
     case when i.id > 0 
         then (select i.id for xml path('parent'),type)
      else null --> don't write this element if id is than 0
end )
```

And i get,

```
 <parent>
  <id>some id number </id></parent>
```

But, I'm looking for

```
<id>some id number </id>
```

Any suggestion....

Comment: What happens if you remove `parent` from path? Just use an empty string `''`.

Comment: Thanks...and using a empty string works.  But, is that the most effective way way to solve the problem ?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that solution. There might be other ways to do it but it is hard to tell without the context of the full query and I don't think you would notice any difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the empty string '' instead of 'parent'.